# Print calendar of current month

Tags: sqlite

It seems my exercise has not any practical usage but I wanna understand where is my issue covered. I'm trying to print the calendar of the current month (starting with Monday), so my vision of resolving this problem is next. First, it need to get total number days in the month.

```
 WITH days(total) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT total + 1 FROM days
    LIMIT (
       SELECT CAST(
          julianday('now', 'start of month', '+1 month') -
          julianday('now', 'start of month') AS INTEGER
       )
    )
 ) SELECT group_concat(total) FROM days;
```

Second, it need N spaces before if first day of month is not Monday.

```
 WITH days(total) AS (
    WITH spaces(nil) AS (
       SELECT CHAR(32)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT nil FROM spaces
       LIMIT (
          SELECT strftime('%w', julianday('now', 'start of month')) -1
       )
    ) SELECT group_concat(nil) || 1 FROM spaces
    UNION ALL
    SELECT total + 1 FROM days
    LIMIT (
       SELECT CAST(
          julianday('now', 'start of month', '+1 month') -
          julianday('now', 'start of month') AS INTEGER
       )
    )
 ) SELECT group_concat(total) FROM days;
```

Third, theare are two problems: last day of month gets lost and how to split sequence for equal chunks? Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found [here](https://github.com/gregzakh/notes/blob/master/sqlite/README.md).

```
WITH seg(b, s) AS ( -- split string on segments
   VALUES (1, '')
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b + 21, SUBSTR((
      WITH nil(e) AS ( -- spaces (if not a Monday)
         SELECT CHAR(32)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT e FROM nil
         LIMIT (
            SELECT ( -- Sunday is presented by zero, so fix this
               CASE WHEN dow = CAST(0 AS INTEGER) THEN 7 ELSE dow END
            ) FROM ( -- day of week
               SELECT strftime('%w', julianday('now', 'start of month')) AS dow
            )
         )
      ) SELECT replace( -- replace all commas on spaces
         'Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su,' || rtrim(group_concat(printf('%2s', e))) || (
            WITH seq(n) AS ( -- days sequence
               SELECT 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
               LIMIT (
                  SELECT CAST(
                     julianday('now', 'start of month', '+1 month') -
                     julianday('now', 'start of month') AS INTEGER
                  )
               )
            ) SELECT group_concat(printf('%2s', n)) FROM seq
      ), ',', CHAR(32)) FROM nil
   ), b, 21) FROM seg
   LIMIT 8
) SELECT s FROM seg;
```